# In an NxN matrix give value "True" to pairs from data frame

Tags: r, matrix

I have created a 5x5 matrix where rows and columns have the same names and a data frame with name pairs:

```
N <- 5
Names <- letters[1:N]

mat <- matrix(rep(0, N*N), nrow = N, ncol = N, dimnames = list(Names, Names))

  a b c d e
a 0 0 0 0 0
b 0 0 0 0 0
c 0 0 0 0 0
d 0 0 0 0 0
e 0 0 0 0 0
```

The data frame then consist of different pairs:

```
  col1 col2
1    a    c
2    c    b
3    d    b
4    d    e
```

How can I match these in so that col1 only refers to rows in my matrix and col2 only to columns? The above should compute to the following result:

```
  a b c d e
a 0 0 1 0 0
b 0 0 0 0 0
c 0 1 0 0 0
d 0 1 0 0 1
e 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` to create a "key" of which combinations need to be replaced with 1, like this:

```
key <- vapply(seq_along(mydf), 
              function(x) match(mydf[[x]], 
                                dimnames(mat)[[x]]), 
              numeric(nrow(mydf)))
```

Then, use matrix indexing to replace the relevant values.

```
mat[key] <- 1
mat
  a b c d e
a 0 0 1 0 0
b 0 0 0 0 0
c 0 1 0 0 0
d 0 1 0 0 1
e 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
 mat[as.matrix(d1)] <- 1
 mat
 #  a b c d e
 #a 0 0 1 0 0
 #b 0 0 0 0 0
 #c 0 1 0 0 0
 #d 0 1 0 0 1
 #e 0 0 0 0 0
```

#### data

```
 d1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("a", "c", "d", "d"), col2 = c("c", "b", 
  "b", "e")), .Names = c("col1", "col2"), class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```